# Next js login with laravel rest api and Github Auth

Tags: laravel, github, next.js

I have a problem for github auth login. I'm using laravel api for backend and next js for frontend. I want to do is user can be login with their github account . I already installed laravel socialite package for social login .But following error in showing in frontend

[error image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QRxG.png)

This is Github Controller code

```
class GithubController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('github')->redirect();
    }

    public function callback()
    {
        try {
            $token = auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;
            $user = Socialite::driver('github')->userFromToken($token);
            $gitUser = User::updateOrCreate([
                'github_id' => $user->id,
            ], [
                'name' => $user->name,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'auth_type' => 'github',
                'github_token' => $user->token,
                'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(24)),
            ]);

            Auth::login($gitUser);

            $cookie = cookie(name: 'IncomeController', value: $token, minutes: 60 * 24);
            // return the token as a response
            return ResponseHelper::success('Login Successfully', [
                'userId' => auth()->user()->id,
                'userName' => auth()->user()->name,
                'access_token' => $token,
                'token_type' => 'Bearer'
            ])->withCookie($cookie);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

This is cors.php
`'paths' => ['*'],

```
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL'), env('FRONTEND_LOCAL_URL'), '*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,`
```

This is laravel api.php

```
Route::get('/auth/github', [GithubController::class, 'redirect'])->name('github.login');
Route::get('/auth/github/callback',  [GithubController::class, 'callback']);
```

This is next js login form

```
  const handleGithubLogin = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Github login');
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/github', {
        method: 'GET',
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        // Do something with the token, such as storing it in local storage
      } else {
        // Handle the error response
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle the network error
    }
  };
```

Could you help me if there any idea? Sorry for your time.

I tried as like this doc
[github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps)
[github forum](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24602)
[laravel socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/socialite#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result like this,

Step 1: First get the redirect_uri and send it to frontend,

```
public function redirect()
{
    $redirect_uri = Socialite::driver('github')->stateless()->redirect()->getTargetUrl();

    return response()->json($redirect_uri);
}
```

Step 2: Then redirect the responce url from frontend,

```
const handleLogin = () => {
   axios.get("/api/login/github").then((res) => {
     router.replace(res.data);
   });
};
```

Step 3: Create a callback page on frontend, make sure to add this url on provider callback. On this page get 'code' response from provider and send it to backend callback by a get request, then Socialite will handle the rest

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const loginWithGithub = async () => {
      await csrf();

      axios
        .get(`/api/login/github/callback?code=${router.query.code}`)
        .then(() => {
          router.push("/dashboard");
        });
    };

    if (router.query.code) {
      loginWithGithub();
    }
  }, [router.query.code]);
```

Step 4: retrieve & logged in the user

```
public function callback()
    {
        $githubUser = Socialite::driver('github')->stateless()->user();

        // Add your logic to create or log in the user here
        $user = User::updateOrCreate([
            'email' => $githubUser->email,
        ], [
            'name' => $githubUser->name,
            'email' => $githubUser->email,
        ]);

        Auth::login($user);

        // response
        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

Now you are logged in on frontend. Hope that solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I aprreciate this.